# Using Appium with Ruby I get: ERROR: Unable to connect to Appium. Is the server running? (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, appium-ios

I have the appium.dmg client running with:

Server Address: 127.0.0.1
Port: 4723

but Im Receiving the following error after attempting to run my Ruby Appium script

`/Users/tboland/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec /Users/tboland/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/tboland/RubymineProjects/AppiumProject/FirstScript/launch_safari_on_ios_device.rb
/Users/tboland/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/appium_lib-8.0.2/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:492:in`rescue in start_driver': ERROR: Unable to connect to Appium. Is the server running? (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/tboland/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/appium_lib-8.0.2/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:477:in ``start_driver'
    from /Users/tboland/RubymineProjects/AppiumProject/FirstScript/launch_safari_on_ios_device.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in`load'
    from -e:1:in `'

Process finished with exit code 1`

Here is the Ruby code:

**Gemfile:**

`source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'appium_lib'

gem 'appium_console'

gem 'selenium-webdriver'`

**launch_safari_on_ios_device.rb**

`require 'rubygems'
require 'appium_lib'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Defining Desired Capabilities for the Driver
desired_capabilities = {

```
caps: {

    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '9.3',
    browserName: 'safari',
    #iPod Touch
    deviceName: 'aaaa',
    udid:'#####'
}
```

}

Create appium driver
@driver = Appium::Driver.new(desired_capabilities).start_driver
sleep 5
@driver.get "http://androidsdet.blogspot.com"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an Appium server up and running waiting for your test to connect. This could be in your own localhost or alternatively on some remote server or cloud service.

The Appium ruby client sets the server to use your localhost by default, unless you provide SauceLabs user details. For other use cases, you will need to provide a value to the server_url variable to target a specific server or service.

For Appium webdriver the values such as server_url need to be provided within appium_lib. See the simple_test.rb example from Appium's sample-code page: https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/ruby/simple_test.rb#L36

With Selenium Webdriver, the init of the webdriver could look like this:

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => desired_capabilities, :url => server_url, :http_client => http_client)
```

To see how to set up your own Appium server to your localhost, please refer to Appium's README at https://github.com/appium/appium

Comment: Yes...I have the Appium.dmg client up and running on my mac before I run this test.  Server Address:  127.0.0.1 Port: 4723 - which i believe is Appiums default

Comment: Can you confirm that the Appium.dmg launched the server correctly? Did the server logs give any indication that you tried to launch a webdriver session against it?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have appium already running and are trying to start another session using the same port. 
Use the command `killall node` on terminal and then run Appium again